# How to upload a Serialized Media Tree?

Tags: serialization

I serialized the media tree on my old site. I copy/paste into my new site: App_Data\serialization

How can I update the Media Tree from here?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is in `Developer` tab in ribbon in the `Serialize` group, click `Update Tree`.

Select media library node and then click the button. I assume you serialized the whole media library from the old site. If you don't want the whole media library, still do serialize all the ancestors of the items you need up to media library root.

`Developer` tab may be hidden. If yes, right click the ribbon and check `Developer` there.

[image]